# problem regarding multiple random variables and normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I try to solve the following out of an old book on statistics:

> Cardboard boxes are stacked. The boxes have an average height of 10 cm and the height is normally distributed with a standard deviation of 1 cm. The maximum height of the building is 106 cm.
>
> If boxes are picked at **random**, determine the chance of:
>
> - **not** having enough space to stack 10 boxes;
> - having enough space to stack 11 boxes;
> - having enough space to stack 10 boxes but **not** having any space (left) for a extra 11'th box.

#### My solution

Let $X\stackrel{d}{=} N(10,1)$ then $Y=10X \stackrel{d}{=}N(100,10)$ and $U=11X\stackrel{d}{=}N(110,11)$

The solution for the first problems is quickly found using the standard-normal distribution.

- $\mathcal{P}(Y\geqslant 106) = 0,0287$
- $\mathcal{P}(Z\leqslant 106) = 0,1131$
- The last 'problem' is bugging me. I tried the following:

$\mathcal{P}(Y\leqslant 106, Z\geqslant 106)$
$= \mathcal{P}(Y\leqslant 106)\cdot \mathcal{P}(Z\geqslant 106) = (1-0,0287)\cdot (1-0,1131) \approx 0,8614$

The book proposes the solution: 0,8582. (the difference isn't big, but I wonder what causes it?, the other (sub)answers align perfectly with the book)

I guess breaking the condition isn't allowed since $Y$ and $Z$ are not indepent? But I don't have any idea how to continue without it...

Answer (score 1):

It should be clear that $A=\left\lbrace Z\leq 106\right\rbrace \subset \left\lbrace Y\leq 106\right\rbrace=B$ -- if $11$ fit then so do $10$. What you want is the probability of $\left\lbrace Y\leq 106\right\rbrace\setminus\left\lbrace Z\leq 106\right\rbrace=B\setminus A$. Since
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{P}(B)=\mathbf{P}(B\setminus A)+\mathbf{P}(B\cap A),
\end{equation*}
we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}(B\setminus A)&=\mathbf{P}(B)-\mathbf{P}(B\cap A)\\
&=\mathbf{P}(B)-\mathbf{P}(A)\\
&=(1-0.0287)-(0.1131)\\
&=0.8582
\end{align*}